# Connection refused [Exception: java.net.ConnectException]

Tags: codenameone

I'm running a simple CodenameOne app where an image is downloaded and displayed in the form.

'

```
int WIDTH = Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth();
        Form f = new Form();
        f.getToolbar().hideToolbar();
        f.getStyle().setBgColor(0xFFFFFF);
        EncodedImage placeholder = EncodedImage.createFromImage(Image.createImage(WIDTH, WIDTH), false);
        URLImage puppyImage = URLImage.createToStorage(placeholder, "puppy.png", "https://images.newscientist.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/03141753/03-june_puppies.jpg?crop=1:1,smart&width=1200&height=1200&upscale=true");
        Container imageContainer = new Container();
        imageContainer.add(puppyImage);
        f.add(imageContainer);
        f.show();
```

'

I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly (or did incorrectly), while I used a proxy everything ran fine, and the image is downloaded and saved. Now if I run the app without the proxy I get the following error and stack trace:

'

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:101)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:608)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:557)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:182)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:526)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:524)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.privilegedOpenServer(HttpClient.java:523)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:265)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:372)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:212)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1208)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:189)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1592)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:527)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:334)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.getResponseCode(JavaSEPort.java:10179)
    at com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.performOperationComplete(ConnectionRequest.java:905)
    at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager$NetworkThread.runCurrentRequest(NetworkManager.java:314)
    at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager$NetworkThread.run(NetworkManager.java:390)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

'
I would like to know what is causing this and how I can fix it, Thanks.

Comment: It's possible the server is blocking requests that look suspicious or that the you're behind a proxy that's preventing the connection from going through. Make sure to configure your Java proxy settings and also check out the simulators network monitor for deeper details about the incoming/outgoing traffic.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. When I run the simple app on my device it runs flawless. So I'll work with it as is until I can rectify it better. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue!
I realized I manually set proxy settings in the simulator.

[image: Codename One Simulator Network Proxy Settings]